# Why is the compiler conflicting with a namespace in inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, compiler-errors

In the following code

```
namespace Too
{
    public class Foo
    {

    }
}

namespace Foo
{

    public class Boo : Foo
    {

    }
}
```

I get the error `'foo' is a namespace but is used like a type`.
The error goes away if I fully qualify the `Foo` class name as `Too.Foo` in the inheritance.

Why would the compiler attempt to resolve the `Foo` namespace instead of the class in a place where a namespace doesn't make sense ?

Comment: I guess its feeling stupid .. but it does seem odd that it wouldnt know to use the right thing.

Comment: Because in the scope of the namespace `Foo`, `Foo` refers to the namespace. That's the way the compiler is built. You will have to reference the full type name here, `public class Boo : Too.Foo`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yes, but why is the compiler attempting to use a namespace in a place where a namespace would never be valid ? A class can't inherit from a namespace ... My question isn't how to make this code work but why it works this way ?

Comment: I don't see a problem of specifying fully qualifying name. Is it a problem or what are you going to do with the answer?

Comment: @MathieuVIALES The compiler doesn't make that call for one of two reasons: Either it would cause problems that aren't obvious to you, or else there have always been more important features for the team to work on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't care much about if your reference is a class or a namespace when it first resolves names. If a name isn't fully qualified, it will always try to find it in the local namespace first - including the namespace name itself. If it can't find it in the local namespace it will try the `using` directives.

The reason it resolves it like that is, that you can after all create a namespace hierarchy and all classes and namespaces are separated by `.`. Thus while resolving names, the compiler doesn't care much about the type but only about the hierarchy path. It will care about the type though as soon as it has found a match. In this case it is a namespace when it expects a class and thus fails.

With sub-namespaces and sub-classes it'd be hard for the compiler to identify a match if it simply tries to fit one and it might find multiple references if it just matches random namespaces in the same assembly. Thus it's always local namespace first, then moves up the hierarchy through to other assemblies. If it's not clear because two sub-namespaces or classes with the same name exist in different namespaces that are both referenced, you have to be even more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Because Foo is in a different namespace. When inheriting Foo

```
namespace Foo 
{

    class Boo: Foo {
```

you are not specifying which Foo you are referring to. Is it Foo the namespace or Too.Foo

Comment: I think OP knows this. The question is: why isn't the compiler implemented in a way that this could work. I mean, it's obvious that you don't want to inherit a namespace, but a class (or interface), and I can't see what could possibly go wrong if the compiler would make that decision. But in fact, only the compiler-developers can answer this question.

Comment: yes, but why would the compiler attempt to use the `foo` namespace where a namespace would never be valid ?

Comment: It's not magic after all. Also it ensures better code readability (this point is enough to validate the error in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't find `class Foo` in the `namespace Foo` where you are trying to inherit a new class. You **must** fully qualify the name, it's not something you can't skip or not do, unless:

```
namespace Foo
{
    using Too;

    public class Boo : Foo // now is ok, compiler will look into `Too` too
    {
    }
}
```

Without `using` or fully qualified name compiler **is not even looking** into `namespace Too`. Try to use any type e.g. `List<T>` without specifying it fully or without `using System.Collections.Generic` in methods, same problem, you will get an error

> The type or namespace name 'Foo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

---

As for an error:

> CS0118    'Foo' is a namespace but is used like a type

You get this because compiler found within the scope (if I can say so) `Foo`, which happens to be a namespace and which you should not use as a base type.

---

@RenéVogt has formulated the question better:

> why isn't the compiler implemented in a way that this could work

For an answer we have to ask developers. But in my understanding it would not be a huge gain and worth effort to achieve that. Personally I don't see a problem with telling compiler specifically where to look.

Think about this case:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Foo { }
    public class Boo : Foo { }
    public class BooToo : Foo { } // here I want Too.Foo, how?
}
```

Even if compiler look into `namespace Too` you will have a conflict anyway.

Comment: I guess OP is not asking the reason why the compiler isn't accepting Foo without the full name qualification, but why it is not guessing that the code in that particular point is necessarily referring to a class, simply because a namespace isn't allowed there.